# How do I split a text file into parts in C?

Tags: c, text, divide, chunks

Suppose I have a text file that says:
*This file has plain text*

Now, I want to divide this text file into 'n' number of parts with equal characters.
Suppose the user wants three divisions, then 1.txt, 2.txt and 3.txt should be created, with about 8 characters each.

(The next part of this program is to rejoin these files back into the original state but I'm sure I'll be able to do that myself If I can get help with this first part).

Can you guys guide me in this matter?

Language used is C.

```
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int iChunkNo=0;
char cFileName[30];

iChunkNo = atoi(argv[2]);
strcpy(cFileName, argv[1]);

printf("The file will be divided into %d chunks \n", iChunkNo);

FILE* file_read_pointer;
file_read_pointer = fopen(cFileName, "r");

int iCount=0;
char ch;

while (1) 
{
        ch = fgetc(file_read_pointer);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        ++iCount;
}

printf("The number of characters in the file is: %d \n", iCount);   

int iCharPerFile = 0;
iCharPerFile = iCount/iChunkNo;

printf("The number of characters per chunk file will be: %d \n", iCharPerFile);

FILE* file_write_pointer;   

int j=1;
for(j; j<=iChunkNo; j++)
{   
    char num[5] = {j};
    char ext[4] = {"txt"};

    char name[15];
    sprintf(name, "%d.%s", j, ext);     

    FILE* file_write_pointer;
    file_write_pointer = fopen(name, "w");
}

int i=0;

for(i; i<iCharPerFile; i++)
{
    char temp;
    temp = fgetc(file_read_pointer);
    //fputc(temp, file_write_pointer);
    fprintf(file_write_pointer, "%c", temp);
}
}
```

Comment: This question has distinct look of a homework assignment.

Comment: Are you counting spaces and newlines as characters? If so you could always just first count all characters to get a total divide by 'n' and then output after reading total/'n' characters.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin
I'm not a complete code copier :) I like programming but it pisses me off when I get stuck. I'm trying to post my code. See comments below. Won't allow me to post it here.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Since I'm a student, yes this IS a homework assignment. But I'm not relying entirely on help. Posted what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

- Find the size of the file (using `fseek` and `ftell`). Then seek back to the beginning
- Determine the size you need to write to each file (size / n)
- Read one character at a time (use `getc`) and write to the corresponding file (`putc`)

  - Use `sprintf(fname, "%d.txt", index)` to build names like "1.txt"
  - Use `fopen` to open files and keep a `FILE *current` to which you write at each step

That being said, you should start slow. First make a program that simply copies one file into another using `getc` + `putc` and work your way up.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already have a program of my own that copies text from one file to another.
In this assignment, I have already implemented the following:

1- Check total # of characters
2- Decide on number of characters per file
3- Create the required number of text files.

I'll now try to code keeping in mind your suggestions. Last time I compiled, it only copied a weird YYYYYYYY symbol into the resultant text file lol

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to work out how much text there is in total, possibly by 'slurping' the whole file into memory.  This will work fine for file sizes up to megabytes in size, but not for gigabytes and beyond.

Then you need to know how many parts to split it into (command line argument processing?), and therefore how much data to write to write to each part.  This will be followed by creating each of the output files, writing the right segment of data to the file, and closing it.

Supposing the file has 29 bytes and you need to split it in 3 parts.  Will you create 2 parts with 9 bytes and one with 11, or 2 with 10 and one with 9.  What about if it is 28 bytes long and 5 parts?  (4 x 5 bytes + 1 x 8 bytes?  3 x 6 bytes + 2 x 5 bytes?  Or is that 2 x 5 bytes + 3 x 6 bytes?)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input but I'll be going more by # of characters in file rather than the amount of bytes its taking in the memory. I know they can both be inter-related but I find the # way simpler.